# Go back to my servers IP instead of domain

Tags: server, apache2, dns

So I had this server I set up a while back... made it so it pointed had a couple domains in the vhost. And I just got rid of the domains and want to use it mostly for developing stuff / a sandbox now. When I type the servers IP address again... it automatically points to the domain. How do I make it so it does not automatically point to the domain anymore when I visit the IP address. (I had it setup with auto redirect to the https)

Answer (score 0):

You need create separate VirtualHost for IP like a domain and target it to page you want. It can be 404 page or blank page or something else.

With Apache 2.4, the first vhost will be main host which located by IP, no need "ServerName"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin YourEmail
    DocumentRoot /home/apache/www
    <Directory /home/apache/www/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
Include /path/to/vhosts/*.conf
```